# Organize Rails view so thats its a little easy to read

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have the below code

```
<% @data1.results.map do |s|%>
    <%if params[:data1].empty? == true%>
        s.product.text
            <!-- More content to come-->
    <%else%>
        <% if s.text.include?(params[:data1])%>
            <!--Skip over -->
        <%else%>
            s.product.text
                    <!-- More content to come-->
    <%end%>
        <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Now as you can see

```
s.product.text
<!-- More content to come-->
```

gets repeated. I have just pasted the two lines but there will be more in future. Now I am wondering what is a neat way to have the code placed there without repeating or making the view uneasy to the eyes?   Maybe use Proc ? But how ? I tried having it in helper but didnt work

I had something like

```
@proc = Proc.new {
    s.product.text
    <!-- More content to come-->
}
```

But when I do a `@proc.call` it gives me a `no method error`.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `s.product.text <more content>` in a partial and render it from both places when required.

For more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: yes i tried that but it gave me unknown local variable error (or something similar one :))

Comment: this is the error i get `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 's' for`

Comment: Did you pass the `s` variable into the partial?

Comment: I just replaced `s.product.text
            <!-- More content to come-->` with the partial syntax inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the two conditions so that the repetition is unneeded.

```
<%if !params[:data1].empty? && s.text.include?(params[:data1]) %>
   <!--Skip over -->
<%else%>
   s.product.text
   <!-- More content to come-->
<%end%>
```

But having complex conditions in your views is not such a good idea, so I'd recommend pushing that into a helper, and then your view would look like

```
<%if show_thing?(s) %>
   s.product.text
   <!-- More content to come-->
<% else %>
   <!--Skip over -->
<%end%>
```

where your helper looks something like

```
def show_thing?(s)
  params[:data1].empty? || !s.text.include?(params[:data1])
end
```

It's probably still a good idea to also push the content you want to render for the product into a partial as some of the other answers have suggested. If you always render the same markup for a product, you could even shorten this to

```
<%if show_thing?(s) %>
   <%= render  s.product %>
<% else %>
   <!--Skip over -->
<%end%>
```

which will render the products/_product partial, setting the local variable product to s.product.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. And BTW, you should be using each for looping, unless you want to modify the array.

```
<% @data1.results.each do |s|%>
  <% if params[:data1].empty? == true%>
    <%= render :partial => 'partial_name', :locals => { :text => s.product.text }
  <% else%>
    <% if s.text.include?(params[:data1])%>
        <!--Skip over -->
    <%else%>
        <%= render :partial => 'partial_name', :locals => { :text => s.product.text }
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

now you can use the local variable 'text' in your partial